# Abrir tela como windows explorer

Tags: javascript

Meu sistema possui uma tela similar ao Windows Explorer (Winfile), nesta tela, cada pasta possui uma legenda com o ano atual (2015). O que preciso é que quando chegar o ano de 2016, apareça uma imagem que represente o ano desta pasta, dando a entender que ela está cheia.

- **O meu problema hoje é**:

  1. Como devo fazer para  apresentar os resultados no formato de uma
     tabela listando os anos.
  2. Ao clicar em uma destas pastas do ano, tem que abrir outra galeria, so que representando os meses, seria uma tabela com 4 linhas e 3 colunas e dentro dessas pastas terão os arquivos referentes ao mês consultado.

Gostaria de saber se é preciso armazenar em sessão, ou se tem uma forma melhor de fazer isso.

Comment: Essa pergunta tem uma frase de 682 caracteres!! Dá para formatar com pontos, virgulas e parágrafos para a pergunta ficar mais fácil de ler?

Comment: Dá preguiça mesmo, @Sergio

Comment: O que você tentou?

Comment: @HitchLeonardo, isso é um sistema de álbum, acredito que vc possa fazer tudo isso sem precisar de session, usando CSS e não precisa de tabela, dá pra fazer com float:left nas divs